# xhr Post with JSZip Javascript / JSZip upgrade

Tags: javascript, post, xmlhttprequest, zip, jszip

I'm trying to 'post' and xhr request using a zip file but I'm having trouble getting the zip in the right format. I found a post that showed a similar request using this:

```
var zip = new JSZip(); // create the jszip zip
var input = $("#image")[0]; // Get the image from dom (image is an input button)
zip.file("test.png", input.files[0], {base64: true}); // Add uploaded image to zip

var content = zip.generate({type:"blob"}); // Format zip to blob

//prepare file for api call
var data = new FormData();
data.append("files", content, "Test.zip");
```

First things first, `zip.generate({type:"blob"});` has been deprecated. The upgrade guide states:

```
// 2.x
zip.generate();
// 3.x
zip.generateAsync({type:"uint8array"})
.then(function (content) {
    // use content
});
```

I don't understand what "use content" is. And if I just leave that function blank the code won't run. I'd list the error but I'm using SAP WEB IDE and it simply won't run it, it doesn't display an error.

How can I format the zip to work for an xhr request?

---

Useful links:

- [JSZip upgrade guide](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/upgrade_guide.html)
- [Outdated post example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748168/sending-generated-jszip-zip-file-in-xmlhttprequest-javascript/22372537#22372537)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you try this way

```
zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}).then(function(content) {
  var data = new FormData();
  data.append("files", content, "Test.zip");
});
```

check it here
https://github.com/Stuk/jszip

Comment: The only thing I changed for this to work was moving the 'var data = new FormData();' outside this function so that it can be referenced later for the xhr call. Thanks!